# How can i disable autohiding of the top panel in scribes?

Tags: panel, customization, text-editor, autohide

I liked the scribes text editor very much. But the auto hiding feature of the top panel is annoying. How can I get rid of if. or **Can i disable auto hiding of top panel in scribes?, How?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question was answered to scribes developers PPA in Launchpad. They have said, It is not possible.

> There's no option to disable the top panel.

[Reference](https://answers.launchpad.net/scribes/+question/198852)